# Non trivial solution of a linear homogeneous system with singular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

In Landau&Lifshitz volume 1, chapter 5 section 23, the author imposes that the matrix of a linear system is singular. After finding the $\omega_\alpha$ that make the determinant zero, he proceeds with the substition and states that **if the eigenfrequencies are different, then the solutions of the system are proportional to the minor of the matrix.** (calculated with $\omega=\omega_\alpha$).

Can you provide a motivation for that? Why is the non-trivial solution proportional to the minor? Does that always happen for a singular homogeneous linear system?

A picture of the book below (the blue part is not relevant).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that minors in Landau&Lifshitz are actually cofactors (that is they absorbed $\pm 1$ in the definition of minors). Then the statement follows from $\mathbf{A} \operatorname{adj}(\mathbf{A}) = \det(\mathbf{A}) \mathbf{I}$, which follows from the [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) of the determinant.